# Getting alertdialog selected list values inside OnCreate method when came from child activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist, android-alertdialog

In my app need to select the values in first activity in alert dialog and pass that values to the second activity. It is working . now, When i came back to first activity and without selecting any if i click on filter button it send empty list. how can i bring the values present in the alert dialog to onCreate.

First Activity:

```
 public class AllMovieRating extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Views mViews;
final ArrayList ilist = new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_movie_rating);

    mViews=new Views();
    mViews.irating.setOnClickListener(this);      

}     @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imdb_rating:
         ilist.clear();
            ilist();
            break;

    }

}
private void filtervalues() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AllRating.this,sharedcollect.class);
    intent.putExtra("im",ilist);
    startActivity(intent);

}  public ArrayList ilist() { final String[] ratings = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    final boolean[] ratingschecked = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("checkedrate_i", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("size", 0);
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        imdblist.add(sharedPreferences.getString("selectedratings" + j, null));
       //Log.e("Kumar", "" + selectedratings);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<=ratingschecked.length;j++){
        if(imdblist.contains((String.valueOf(j)))) {
            ratingschecked[j-1] = true;
        }
    }

    builder.setTitle("Select Ratings");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ratings, ratingschecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                   if(!imdblist.contains(ratings[which])){
                       imdblist.add(ratings[which]);

                    }
                //Log.e("Shiva", ""+imdblist);
            } else if (imdblist.remove(ratings[which])) {

               // Log.e("Kumar", String.valueOf(ratings[which]));


            }
        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            // editor.putString("checked", String.valueOf(selectedratings));
            for (int i = 0; i < imdblist.size(); i++) {
                editor.putString("selectedratings" + i, String.valueOf(imdblist.get(i)));
            }
            editor.putInt("size", imdblist.size());
            editor.apply();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.show();
  return imdblist;
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class sharedcollect extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView movielist;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sharedcollect);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("im");




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sharedcollect, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
          onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To second Activity you are sending `final ArrayList ilist` property which is your class variable. But you aere not writing anything to this list.

```
case R.id.imdb_rating:
     ilist.clear();
        ilist();
```

In here xou clear you ilist(property) and then you call your ilist(function) function. ilist() returns type of `ArrayList` and you are ignoring it.

For your test case it should be enought tio write from alert diloag right to class property `final ArrayList ilist`.

```
...
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(ratings, ratingschecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                   if(!ilist.contains(ratings[which])){
                       ilist.add(ratings[which]);
                    }
                //Log.e("Shiva", ""+imdblist);
            } else if (imdblist.remove(ratings[which])) {
               // Log.e("Kumar", String.valueOf(ratings[which]));
                if(ilist.contains(ratings[which])){
                       ilist.remove(ratings[which]);
                    }
            }
        }
    }) 
...
```

and then after clicking on OK button ylou dont need to write this items to shared preferences. It would be enough to start new activity

```
 ...
 .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              filtervalues();
        }
    }).
```

...

Comment: 1) ilist.clear() is used, when i came from second to first and reselect the values but array list sending a newly selected along with already selected items. 2)I declared arraylist as global so that i can send it to another activity. 3)Shared preference is required to remind the selected items and show it to user who used.

Comment: Current code is working but only problem when i launch the app that time i need to get the already selected list items to send to second activity.

Comment: In that case in onCreate method you can parse selected items from preferences and save them to ilist. And in AlertDialogBuilder and then you need to set properly ratingschecked variable. This argument is array of bools and represents on which positions are items selected  {true, false, true} items on index 0 and 2 are selected. You have to do this computation dynamicly from your preferences